# DeviceToken changed evry time i open my app android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have an app android wish work with parse sdk
I put insttalation to get push notification
I have used sdk 1.12.0 of parse
I have make all the step in manifest
The first time that insttall the app i get the push but when i close the app and open it again it has change the devicetoken in the insttalation table in parse and i cant get the push.
Please have you an answer

Comment: Maybe you should provide some code

Answer (score 0):

save token in SharedPreferences and request it only if necessary

Comment: Thank you fot the response but what is the cause for that

Comment: each time a make this line of code i got a new deviceToken 

ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

Comment: I still have the same problem. Have you find a solution?

Comment: have you requested the token only if you do not have it?

Comment: The problem become when i subscribe in the quickblox push because in my app i use sdk quickblox and parse. For quickblox i should use GCM to the push.So when i save installation in parse i got tje first and the right devicetoken after that i have to subscribe to quickblox push and i got an other devicetocken wish will bz saved in parse and in tjat time i will never got the push from parse